# Chartboost test scene not working in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, chartboost

I made an app for android with unity3d, and want to include chartboost into it. I imported the plugin for unity, and added an app as well as a campaign on chartboost. I also made sure that the signature and app name were put into the strings.xml file. When I tried running the demo scene, the buttons appeared, but when I tried to click them, nothing happens, not even a message in the console. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Lagidigu

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, chartboost does not work in the editor. You will need to build to a device and use logcat to see the log messages. However their unity plugin seems to be in need of some fixing- in the meantime, email them at support@chartboost.com and they should send you a workaround .jar file that will get the ads showing in the demo.

See my answer to [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994144/interstitials-not-displaying-but-impressions-being-counted/22045952#22045952) for details about why the ads aren't showing up using the newest Chartboost unity plugin.

Comment: Thanks for responding Luke. We've updated the Unity download link on our site to include the proper .jar file by default, so the official download should be working now! The official Chartboost download page [here](https://help.chartboost.com/documentation/unity)

Answer (score 0):

I think their plugin is broken because my other apps DO show ads, and i did nothing different except using their latest plugin, which also for me does not work.

Comment: Thing for me is I also use the admob Plugin from prime31, and I get the same problem in the test scnene, nothing seems to appear. Would be a really strange coincidence if admob and chartboost were broken at the same time...