# Interstitials not displaying, but impressions being counted

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, chartboost

I can't get the interstitials to show up in my Unity3d Android game.

I have an Android game in Unity (v3.3.4). I have added Facebook functionality using the Facebook SDK (v5.0.3), and it works perfectly fine. I have also added Chartboost functionality using the methods described in the [Chartboost Platform Integration: Unity](https://help.chartboost.com/documentation/store/unity/integration) documentation and it is misbehaving.

In Chartboost:

- I have added my app (with SDK integration confirmation)
- I have created a publishing campaign and assigned it to my app

That being said, I have been testing the ads in my game and the interstitial never shows. I have all the event delegates printing everything they receive and not a single value is printed (no errors).

```
// Events I listen to...
CBManager.didFailToLoadInterstitialEvent
CBManager.didCloseInterstitialEvent
CBManager.didCacheInterstitialEvent
CBManager.didShowInterstitialEvent
```

When I look at my app overview in Chartboost I can see that **impressions are being counted** as if the interstitial was displayed properly.

I think this may have something to do with the Chartboost Android activity not being brought up properly, but I really don't know. I have seen many people talking about multiple plugins causing problems with the Android manifest and the "MAIN ACTIVITY" intent.

I still have the Chartboost activity as the "MAIN ACTIVITY" as it says it should be in the Chartboost documentation so there shouldn't be a problem (typically the problem is Facebook won't work with other plugins activities being marked "MAIN ACTIVITY", but Facebook works fine).

Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had a very similar problem myself- contacted their support and as I recall they said the problem is that their Unity plugin seems to be receiving ads intended for the newer version of their SDK that hasn't been implemented for Unity- so the problem is on their side. As a workaround, they provided me with a .jar file that accepts the ads it's receiving. Go ahead and E-mail them about it and they should give you the file without too much of a wait. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Any contact information or further details you could provide would be extremely helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, support@chartboost.com is their technical support email- other contact info for chartboost can be obtained [Here](https://help.chartboost.com/contact) Also I believe one of their reps sends you an email when you first sign up with them, so emailing him directly would also work.

Comment: Thanks for responding Luke. We've updated the Unity download link on our site to include the proper .jar file by default, so the official download should be working now! The official Chartboost download page [here](https://help.chartboost.com/documentation/unity)

Comment: I ended up contacting support and I had to take the .jar file from the newest android build and manually replace the "chartboost.jar" file in my android project in unity.  Thanks for the responses.